# AspNetCore Identity in Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, fetch, microsoft-edge

I am using **Identity 2.0** with **AzureAd** in a **.NET Core 2.0** application (React front end). All data calls are made using the **fetch** API; on the server side I either use the `[Authorize]` tag or check the user's ID using `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`.

All of this works fine, both locally and when deployed to Azure, in Chrome and FireFox. However, with Edge the cookie does not seem to be passed to the server. Here's an example call I made on a page load:

```
fetch(getProjectsUrl, { credentials: "same-origin" })
    .then() ....
```

but the `User.Identity` object comes back null. My startup configuration for cookies looks like this:

```
.AddAzureAd(opts => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", opts))            
.AddCookie(opts =>
    {
        opts.Cookie.Domain = "";
    });
```

because I read somewhere that Microsoft browsers will reject cookies where the App Host tries to set the domain (I've also tried with just a simple `.AddCookie()` as well).

The proper cookie (`AspNetCore.Identity.Application`) gets stored in all browsers per developer tools (including in Edge), and the cookie value format looks to be correct (matches FF/Chrome); it's just not making it to the server on my **fetch** calls from Edge.

I wouldn't be surprised to find that it's caused by Edge having a different implementation of **fetch**, but I can't find any straightforward literature on this. I've tried all possible values for the `credentials` key.

Anyone with similar past experiences, or any pointers, would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check the request whether it contains the cookie? Besides, you could also check whether you have change the Edge View advanced settings and disable the cookie on Edge browser.

Comment: The cookie is definitely making it to the browser, as I can see it under F12 > Debugger > Cookies > My site host. Hope I'm understanding your question properly.